# WebKit Conflicts with the type defined in the same file

Tags: java, android, conflict

I'm currently developing simple android app that I wanted to add iframe tag into my app. I'm using WebView android library, everything seems coded in correct way. But when I try to import android.webkit.WebView... It tells me conflicts with the type defined in the same file. I'm try to clean my projects and refresh it and restart the Eclipse program. Still having the same problem.

```
package com.example.projectrandom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView; //Error this line

public class WebView extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_spinnerwheel);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so that can help you!

Answer (score 1):

> It tells me conflicts with the type defined in the same file

```
public class WebView //Change name it's conflicting with actual WebView
```

Compiler can not differentiate between  `android.webkit.WebView;` and your class `WebView` because names are *Same*.